# How can I display a spawned child process output as colorised html?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I am developing an electron node js app. (I'm a newbie)

And I have code that starts a process and then display the output in the html window.

But I want to take it a step further, if possible, and also show the output in color. (in my current html custom web component)

How can I do this? Or more specific how can I get hold of the color information, so that I can translate it into html?

Here is part of the code that runs the process:

```
let child

function start(startInfo) {
    output.lines = [`${startInfo.processName} ${startInfo.args.join(' ')}`]

    child = child_process.spawn(startInfo.processName, startInfo.args)

    child.on('error', addOutput)
    child.on('message', addOutput)
    child.on('close', (code, signal) => {
        addOutput('Pipeline closed')
        child = null
    })

    child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8')
    child.stdout.on('data', addOutput)

    child.stderr.setEncoding('utf8')
    child.stderr.on('data', addOutput)
    child.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
        addOutput(`Exited with ${code}`)
        child = null
    })
}

function addOutput(newLine) {
    output.lines = output.lines.concat(['\n', newLine])
}
```

And this it the output I see (HTML):

[image]

How can I get closer to the original console output:

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/chalk/chalk ?

Comment: Not exactly, I'm trying to do the opposite `process output -> html page (with color info)`, `chalk` helps with `logging (in color) -> process output`